# Had never been done or had never been done before

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I watched a video about *Singapore's Marina Bay* yesterday. And the reporter said:

> "This was a great design that had never been done.''

My question is: would it be incorrect if I add ''before'' at the end? Like this:

> ''This was a great design that had never been done **before**.''

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that in normal circumstances, people would interpret the following three sentences in the same way:

> This **was** a great design that **had** never been done.
>   This **was** a great design that **had** never been done **before**.
>   This **was** a great design that **had** never been done **until now**.

With each sentence, the implication is that it is **now** done, or is at least in the process of being done.

The past tense in the first part of the sentence invites a comparison with a differing state in the present. Otherwise, you wouldn't express the idea with the past tense.

Instead, if you want to clearly express the fact that it is *still* not done, you would use the present tense:

> This **is** a great design that **has** never been done.
>   This **is** a great design that **has still** never been done.
>   This **is** a great design that **is still** not done.

Here, the present tense affirms an existing condition (of it not being done).

If you want to express the idea that it might be done in the future, then simply add that to the present-tense sentences:

> This **is** a great design that **has** never been done, but we **hope** to do it soon.
>   This **is** a great design that **has still** never been done, but we **plan** on doing it in the future.
>   This **is** a great design that **is still** not done, but we're **working** on it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If a teacher were critiquing a completed project, the change you suggest is valid.

> "This was a great design that had never been done before."

On the other hand, if an architect has an idea for a new plan, and it's yet to be started, then the original wording might be used.

> "This was a great design that had never been done."

Implicitly, it had never been done, and it might still not be done, perhaps due to impracticality.